# get only specific innerHtml

Tags: jquery

as far i know how to get innerHTML but now i want to get only specified tags. let say i only want those line of tags who contains `test-class`.

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="test-class"> some texts </div>

  <div class="class_1"> some text </div>
</div>

$(functio() {
   $('#parent').html();   
});
```

But my expected result should be `<div class="test-class"> 
   some texts
  </div>.` please give me any idea.

Thanks in advance. ***Edit @Js***

```
<html> <head> 
  /* css & js file attached */

<script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
               return (s) ? this.before(s).remove() : 
               jQuery("&lt;div&gt;").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
                               }
   $(function() {
        var outerHTML = $('#parent').find('.test-class').outerHTML();
        alert(outerHTML);
            });
</script>
</head> <body>

/* the same html code as above */

</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// ref: http://www.yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
  return (s) ? this.before(s).remove() : 
               jQuery("<div>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
}

// get outer html
$(function() {
   var outerHTML = $('#parent').find('.test-class').outerHTML();
});
```

Comment: getting a string value only `undefined`.

Comment: @user: Please post the updated code to see how you are doing it.

Comment: @user: Please check the working demo here: http://jsbin.com/iniriq, i have modified some js code for the outerhtml function.

Comment: Sarfraz, one more thing i want to know. what if we don't know about `tag` or if we have requirement for pleanty of `tags` e.g. `div` `input` `span` `p` etc.. then what should we do.

Answer (score 0):

```
function() {
   $('#parent').find(".test-class").html();   
});
```

Comment: The won't include the `<div class="test-class">`, `</div>` tags.

Comment: you could use `$('#parent').find(".test-class")[0].outerHTML`. This will return the complete html definition (<div class="test-class"...) of the first element with .test-class.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this -

```
$('#parent .test-class').clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html()
```

This will get you the entire HTML from the `test-class` div, the `.clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html()` is there to ensure you get the full HTML mark-up. If you just did -

```
 $('#parent .test-class').html()
```

Only `some texts` would be returned.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/KTHDZ/